# CSS Flexbox - Aligning by card description

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a simple card layout and I want to align it by the card description.
Can anyone help me, please? :)

[image]

Here is a Pen: [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ebRwJy)

Here is my HTML structure:

```
 <div class="card-container">
              <div class="card">
                 <div class="card-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500"></div>
                 <h4 class="card-title">Just a title</h4>
                 <p class="card-desc">A simple description</p>
              </div>

              <div class="card">
                 <div class="card-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500"></div>
                 <h4 class="card-title">Just a title</h4>
                 <p class="card-desc">A simple description</p>
              </div>

              <div class="card">
                 <div class="card-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500"></div>
                 <h4 class="card-title">A  veeeeery very very very large title</h4>
                 <p class="card-desc">omg, that description have broken :(</p>
              </div>

              <div class="card">
                 <div class="card-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500"></div>
                 <h4 class="card-title">Just a title</h4>
                 <p class="card-desc">A simple description</p>
              </div>

              <div class="card">
                 <div class="card-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500"></div>
                 <h4 class="card-title">Just a title</h4>
                 <p class="card-desc">A simple description</p>
              </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You are required to post a complete but minimal example of your problem markup or code **here within your question**, not any third party site, that allows us to duplicate the issue: [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By changing the `.card` elements to

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

and adding `margin-top: auto;` to the descriptions. This will cause the description element to be pushed to the bottom of the card. Because the cards are stretched vertically, the alignment works on the horizontal axis. This would not be the case if you changed `align-items` on the `.card-container` to be something other than `stretch`.

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.card-img img {
  width: 60px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.card-title {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.card-desc {
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: auto;
  line-height: 1rem;
}

.card-container {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.432);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .card {
    flex: 1;
  }
  .card-img img {
    width: 50px;
  }
  .card-title {
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  .card-desc {
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1rem;
  }
  .card-container {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.432);
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500"></div>
    <h4 class="card-title">Just a title</h4>
    <p class="card-desc">A simple description</p>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500"></div>
    <h4 class="card-title">Just a title</h4>
    <p class="card-desc">A simple description</p>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500"></div>
    <h4 class="card-title">A veeeeery very very very large title</h4>
    <p class="card-desc">omg, that description have broken :(</p>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500"></div>
    <h4 class="card-title">Just a title</h4>
    <p class="card-desc">A simple description</p>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500"></div>
    <h4 class="card-title">Just a title</h4>
    <p class="card-desc">A simple description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @chazsolo! You aligned the card descritions by bottom, Is there a way to align these card descriptions by top? :)

Comment: @Johnson Since each flex column is unaware of the others, it's not as simple with flexbox. Using CSS grid would allow you to do something like easily.

Comment: Hmm got it! Ok! I will try! Thanks a lot! :)